# Split a string based on pixel length and not character length

Tags: asp-classic

Is it possible to split a string based on the pixel-length, not the character-length?

I don't want a headline of an article to break line and "destroy" the design.

Comment: It would help if you describe why you would want such a function?

Comment: The reason could be many things... In this case it is just because I don't want a headline of an article to break line and "destroy" the design.

Comment: So why are you not using `white-space:nowrap` to acheive that?  The only way to really know how long a string is going to be is to render it and measure the result.

Comment: `whitespace: nowrap` is workable together with `width: 100px` and `overflow: hidden`. But a perfect solution would be if it was able to automaticly put a "..." behind the string if it overflows? :)

Comment: I agree it would be great to do this server side but not very feasable. There is an article on Code Project website that does this in ASP.NET (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/108236/Truncating-a-text-string-in-ASP-NET-to-fit-within). Otherwise you can do client-side, eg. http://blog.johnavis.com/blog/default.asp?id=589

Comment: The Client-side jQuery solution is PERFECT.. Thanks John :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP pages are working on the **server-side**.

The pixel-length or the characher-length of a text is dependent on which font is being used in the browser **on the client side**.

There are fonts called mono-spaced. That means all the letters of the fonts have fixed length. If you are using this type of font then you can calculate the *pixel-length* of the text. Like:

```
<%
    letter_length = 12 
    pixel_length = letter_length * Len(strHeader)
%>
```

Or, if the font is not a mono-spaced font, then maybe you can create an array of pixel-lengths for the font for yourself. And maybe calculate the pixel-length of the whole text, but I discourage you to do it that way because its much more hard-code needed!

And my question to your question is.. **Why you are trying to achieve that with asp (the server-side language)?**

Comment: Ah, great.. So the short answer would be "No, but it cant be done with JavaScript/jQuery" :) Thanks for the explanation mate